# Implementing derived class with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a templated base class `A` and templated derived class `B` defined in `headers.h` and the implementation goes to `source.cpp`

Below code does not compile as `x` is not in the scope of `B`. The question is what am i doing wrong? I found that if `A` is not templated the code compiles fine (with relevant changes).

```
// headers.h
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
      T x;
}

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    void foo();    // do something with x
}
```

```
// source.cpp
#include headers.h

template <typename T>
void B<T>::foo() {}    // do something with x

// explicit instantiation
template class B<double>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Below code does not compile as `x` is not in the scope of `B`

`A<T>` is a base class of the class template `B`:

```
template<typename T>
class B: public A<T> {
// ...
};
```

Although the member `x` from `A<T>` is actually inherited in `B`, it is not found in `B` because the name `x`, when used inside `B`, is not looked up in its base class `A<T>`. The reason is that name lookups are not performed by default in base classes that depend on template parameters (the base class `A<T>` depends on the template parameter of `B`, i.e., `T`). For the name `x` to be looked up in `A<T>` from `B`, you need to express it either as `this->x` or `A<T>::x`.

> I found that if `A` is not templated the code compiles fine

In this case, the base class does not depend on a template parameter, so the lookup of `x` is performed in the base class and the member `x` is found from `B` even if you don't express it as `this->x` or `A::x`.